# Google gauges in python (reportlab)

Tags: python, reportlab, gauge, google-gauges

I am currently writing a program that will automatically generate PDF files using reportlab (a python module). I would like to know if it would be possible to put google gauges in but not as an image, instead as a request sent to google which outputs the correct gauges based on inputs or whatever it may be.

sorry if this question is unclear but if anyone understands what I mean, any help is very appreciated.

thanks

Comment: There's not really a way to put those in a PDF.  The interactive gauge visualization is done in Flash, so there's not really a way you can put that inside a PDF, especially an interactive one.

Comment: Technically PDF does support Flash, but it seems it would be a bad idea for compatibility and security reasons. http://www.informationweek.com/news/software/productivity_apps/208401424